# EF4 db-first: how to add missing relationships

Tags: entity-framework, database-first

I am using db-first to creating object model for a readonly database, but some relationships are not automatically picked up. For example in Foo.BarId is not automatically connected to  Bar object. If I click on BarId property, I don't see anything to associate it to a Bar in the context menu or properties window. How can I manually claim foreign keys without messing up anything?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Figured out myself... here are the steps:

(On model designer)

1. Delete BarId property from Foo entity.
2. Right click Foo entity (not any of its properties), add association between Foo and Bar.
3. Click the association arrow.
4. In Mapping Details window, add "Foo" table.
5. Map Foo.Id to Foo.Id, map Bar.Id to Foo.BarId.

Done.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure that both tables have primary keys and Bar table has foreign key defined.

Comment: The database is readonly. Is there a way to fix it on the model?

Comment: It could be possible to fix in the model but you will run into a problem when saving/updating the entities in the database. Anyway,it's possible to establish a relation by using association in model designer. Just right click on the designer, Add -> Association
and setup the association between these entities.